# Mysql Searching Censored Value in PHP

Tags: mysql

I have a censored value called `ID` (`**85***80**`) and this `ID` value is in a database.

How can I search through mysql based on the `ID` value?

Is it possible to make such a call, if possible how can I do it?

API gives this ID value (`**85***80**`).
And i will search into mysql to find the uncensored version of this ID value.

I WANT IT TO GIVE ME THIS RESULT WHEN I RESEARCH IN MYSQL `11852228024`

Comment: Do you at least know what table or database it is in?  Or are we talking search the entire database?  Yep the answer below is basically why I asked .. if you need a DYNAMIC look in EVERY column .. that is possible .. but highly inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just i need a sql query for making this query

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: mysql version 8.0.21

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with MySQL's `LIKE` clause. The wildcard character for this clause is the underscore `_` character.

Example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE id LIKE '__85___80__';
```

Comment: Working demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/4DlPQ1kw

Comment: You can use a parameterized query and use a string with the formatted target. Example `... LIKE @myParam`. It does not have to be a stored procedure but certainly could!

Comment: I'm trying right now

Comment: Thanks for the demo @ADyson! I edited my answer to remove the leading and trailing `%` characters as those would actually cause matches to occur on any additional characters beyond the wildcard chars. They aren't actually needed in this example. They would be needed if you need a variable number of wildcard matches though.

Comment: You could also use RLIKE with a regular expression pattern.

Comment: Glad to help, @Mxrcy! If this answer worked for you please consider marking it as the accepted answer for your question.